# Binding ModelVisual3D children to an Observable collection in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, 3d

Not sure if I'm going about this the wrong way, but I have an application where a user creates various cuboid objects of different dimensions and positions. These objects are displayed in a Viewport3D and the user can add/edit/delete them and can move the object by doing a drag/drop which should update the underlying data. The cuboids are defined relative to some base coordinate system (meaning that I have nested cuboids where the local coordinates are relative to some parent object).  The data itself needs to be persisted for later re-use.  I'm currently storing the data in an observable collection that I serialize.  However, what I'm not sure is how to dynamically create a ModelVisual3D and have it be bound to a list object that contains a MatrixTransform3D which defines those properties.  A DataTemplate does not appear to be usable on a ModelVisual3D or the Children because it is a VisualCollection and not an ItemsControl object. I'm not sure if I'm thinking of this the wrong way and if so, any suggestions would be appreciated.  Can this be done in XAML or is this all code-behind? I've seen a possible code-behind solution, but is there a way to take advantage of letting the XAML do it? --> [How can I use databinding for 3D elements like Visual3D or UIElement3D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725313/how-can-i-use-databinding-for-3d-elements-like-visual3d-or-uielement3d)